# (play-2.2.1-java) How to set selected option value for enum object property?

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I am having a problem pre-selecting an option of an HTML combo box for the enum object property. Here's a description of my code. I have a Company model class that contains a list of CompanyPhone(s):

```
@Entity
public class Company {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CompanyPhone> phones;
...
}
```

The CompanyPhone has a phoneType property of type PhoneType, which is enum:

```
@Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE")
public PhoneType type;
```

Below is PhoneType enum with static options() method to get a Map for displaying select box options in the HTML template:

```
public enum PhoneType {
    @EnumValue("MAI") MAIN,
    @EnumValue("MOB") MOBILE, 
    @EnumValue("FAX") FAX, 
    @EnumValue("CUS") CUSTOM;

    public static Map<String, String> options() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (PhoneType v : PhoneType.values()) {
            try {
                EnumValue a = v.getClass().getField(v.name()).getAnnotation(EnumValue.class);
            options.put(a.value(), Messages.get(String.format("%s.%s", 
                    PhoneType.class.getSimpleName(), v.name())));
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) { /* ignore */ }
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

Based on Ebean documentation I've chosen to use @EnumValue annotation to specify the value that will be stored in the database. I also implemented formatter to convert between the PhoneType enum and String and registered it in onStart method of Global.java in the root package:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Formatters.register(PhoneType.class, new PhoneTypeFormatter());
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

And here's the formatter class just for reference:

```
public class PhoneTypeFormatter extends SimpleFormatter<PhoneType> {
    @Override
    public PhoneType parse(String input, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        PhoneType phoneType = null;
        for (PhoneType v : PhoneType.values()) {
            try {
                EnumValue a = v.getClass().getField(v.name()).getAnnotation(EnumValue.class);
                    if (input != null && a != null && input.equals(a.value())) {
                        phoneType = v; 
                        break;
                    }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) { /* ignore */ }
        }
        return phoneType;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(PhoneType phoneType, Locale locale) {
        String v = null;
            try {
                v = (phoneType.getClass().getField(phoneType.name())
                        .getAnnotation(EnumValue.class)).value();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) { /* ignore */     }
            return v;
    }
}
```

Now, to display the input fields for multiple phones I use Play2 @repeat directive in the HTML template file. Here's an extract:

```
...
@phoneGroup(field: Field, className: String = "companyPhone") = {
    <div class="control-group @className">
        <label class="control-label"  for="@field("type").id">@Messages("company.phoneNumbers")</label>
        <div class="controls">
                  <select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
            @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
                <option value="@value" 
                  @if(field("type").value != null && value == field("type").value) { selected }>@text</option>
            }
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="inputAreaCode" id="@field("areaCode").id" 
                    name="@field("areaCode").name" value="@field("areaCode").value"
                    placeholder="@Messages("phone.areaCode")">
            <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="@field("number").id" 
                    name="@field("number").name" value="@field("number").value"
                    placeholder="@Messages("phone.number")">
            <a class="removePhone btn btn-danger">@Messages("button.remove")</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
...
@main {
...
    <div class="companyPhones well">
        @repeat(companyForm("phones"), min = 1) { phone =>
            @phoneGroup(phone)
        }
        @**
         * Keep the hidden block that will be used as template for Javascript copy code.
         **@
        @phoneGroup(
            companyForm("phones[x]"), 
            className = "companyPhone_template") 

        <div class="manage_repeat">
            <a class="addPhone btn btn-success">@Messages("phone.add")</a>
    </div>
    </div>
...
}
```

So far so good. When I fill up the form and submit the data the phone numbers are properly stored in the database. But when I use the same form to edit existing data, the current phone type option is not selected in the combo box. It seems that the @if directive highlighted below in red doesn't do the job. However there are no errors displayed:

```
@phoneGroup(field: Field, className: String = "companyPhone") = {
...
    <select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
    @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
        <option value="@value" 
            @if(field("type").value != null && value == field("type").value) { selected }>@text</option>
    }
    </select>
...
}
```

I tried to display the current value of @field("type").value in the span element (highlighted in blue) before the select and the output value on HTML page is correct, however the current value of "FAX" is not selected:

```
@phoneGroup(field: Field, className: String = "companyPhone") = {
...
    <span>Selected type: @field("type").value</span>
    <select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
    @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
        <option value="@value" 
            @if(field("type").value != null && value == field("type").value) { selected }>@text</option>
    }
    </select>
...
}
```

The template above outputs the following HTML:

```
...
<span>Selected type: FAX</span>
<select id="phones_0__type" name="phones[0].type" class="input-small">
    <option value="MAI">Main</option>
    <option value="MOB">Mobile</option>
    <option value="FAX">Fax</option>
    <option value="CUS">Custom</option>
</select>
...
```

I am stuck here. I am not familiar with Scala and the Scala documentation for templates is not very intuitive for me. I also tried to display the value of @field("type").value instead of "selected", just for fun, like that:

```
@phoneGroup(field: Field, className: String = "companyPhone") = {
...
    <span>Selected type: @field("type").value</span>
        <select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
        @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
            <option value="@value" 
                @if(field("type").value != null) { @field("type").value }>@text</option>
        }
        </select>
 ...
}
```

And it output correct value but in lower case:

```
...
<span>Selected type: FAX</span>
<select id="phones_0__type" name="phones[0].type" class="input-small">
    <option value="MAI" fax>Main</option>
    <option value="MOB" fax>Mobile</option>
    <option value="FAX" fax>Fax</option>
    <option value="CUS" fax>Custom</option>
</select>
...
```

This looks strange that in one place it outputs in upper case and in the other in lower case. So, after that another try was just to compare a string value directly like that:

```
...
<span>Selected type: @field("type").value</span>
<select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
    @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
        <option value="@value" 
        @if(field("type").value != null && "FAX".equals(field("type").value)) { selected  }>@text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Still no luck here. In any case I still can't figure out how to achieve the desired result, so that the current value (in this case "FAX") gets selected in the combo box. Can you, please, suggest how to do that or is there any other alternative approach?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE 2013-11-06 - found solution that works for me:**

OK folks, after some browsing through the scala/views/helper files in Play source tree, I tried the if statement that I found in the inputRadioGroup.scala.html

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputRadioGroup.scala.html

So I changed the if statement in my template as follows:

```
<select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
    @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
        <option value="@value" 
        @if(field("type").value != null && Some(value) == (field("type").value)){ selected }>@text</option>
    }
</select>
```

So using ***Some(value)*** fixed the problem and the current option is now selected in the combo box. I don't really understand what that means, I probably need to learn a little bit of Scala to understand templates better, but it works.

Comment: That's a hell of a question... Nice.

Comment: I am looking for a hell of an answer ;-) Posted it on playframework google group mailing list too. Didn't figure out how to make it work yet.